# How to control visual order of plots and fills within the same script?

Tags: pine-script

I can't figure out how to change the visual order of plots and fills within the same script. For example, in a basic script I have bollinger bands with a fill() between the upper and lower bands. In the same script I have plots for a 20 period SMA and VWAP. The plots always appear behind the fill, no matter if I call them before or after the fill in the script. Is it possible to make them appear on top of fills within the same script?

With my trial and error so far the only thing I can think of is creating separate studies - one with the plots and one with the fills. This is fine for simple studies, but I have some pretty complicated ones that already are slow and putting those twice on a chart, especially with several charts open across multiple 4k screens, really bogs down my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this.

When you code usually you code the inputs then the functions and then at last you plot everything. The things you plot at the last will appear at the front of everything. So write the plot code in the order, keeping the thing you want to show on the front at the last.

Blessings.